# Linear subspace definition

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Usually vector space is well defined by addition and multiplication rules, either between 'scalars' and vectors, or between vectors themselves.

How can I prove that the following addition and multiplication between members form a vector space:

$$u + v = uv \space ; \space \space u,v \in R^{+}.$$
$$a \cdot u = u^{a} \space ; \space \space u \in R^{+} \space \space \space a \in R.$$

When they clearly break the rules?

Comment: They don't form a vector space so it should be impossible to prove that it is.

Comment: "Or between vectors themselves". This is not true. The operations in a vector space are always addition and multiplication by a scalar. In some spaces, like in the space of real numbers the elements are just both vectors and scalars, that's why we are allowed to multiply them. But we don't think of it as of product of vectors.

Comment: @CyclomoticField I edited the multiplication, was that the problem?

Comment: Now it looks correct.

Comment: @Mark so how can I prove that this definition of multiplication and addition form a real vector space

Comment: Just check the axioms of a vector space. There are $8$ axioms which have to be satisfied. I'll give an example. One of the axioms states are $a(u+v)=au+av$ for every scalar $a$ and all vectors $u,v$. Let's check it with your operations. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $u,v\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$. Then by the definitions $a(u+v)=(uv)^a=u^av^a=au+av$. Now similarly you have to check the other axioms.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of properties to check. So, check them. For instance, addition is commutative because$$u+v=uv=vu=v+u.$$And we have $(a+b)u=au+bu$ (if $a,b\in\Bbb R$ and $u\in\Bbb R_+$) because$$(a+b)u=u^{a+b}=u^au^b=u^a+u^b=au+bv.$$And so on…

Comment: Even though u and v are vectors, why do you say that u + v = uv? Isn't uv suppose to mean:
 $$u \times v$$
And why does
$$au = u^a$$ 
What am I missing?  
Because as far as I remember if u is a vector and a is a scalar:
$$a \cdot u = (a \cdot u_{1}, \cdots, a \cdot u_{n}) .$$

Comment: It is to me who said that $u+v=uv$. *You* said it. That's the problem that you raised, right?!

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now!